# tapestry persisting objects fails

Tags: tapestry

We are currently migrating our tapestry application to a new server using java 1.7. the application was running smoothly until this migration where most the features in the application broke down. After analysis we found out that objects annotated with @Persist are no longer persisted.

btw:

same Tomcat version

same OS

using tapetsry 5.3.6 and related jars.

does it have todo with the java version or something else? any help?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the default for @Persist is "Session" which in your case should be true in theory. But as you said, that is no longer the case.

Persist tends to go through the entire hierarchy in order to determine its default value.

Perhaps in your case, somehow somebody in a class, that is in a higher hierachy level, used the Annotation `@Meta("tapestry.persistence-strategy=flash")` which automatically sets all @Persist in your program to "flash".

You could try to find out what happened if you implement a HttpSesseionListener and debug through that one so you could find out if your session is beeing created at all.

```
   import java.util.Date; 
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession; 
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent; 
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener; 


public class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener { 
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) 
    { 
        HttpSession session = se.getSession(); 
        System.out.print(getTime() + " (session) Created:"); 
        System.out.println("ID=" + session.getId() + " MaxInactiveInterval=" 
+ session.getMaxInactiveInterval()); 
    } 
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) 
    { 
        HttpSession session = se.getSession(); 
        // session has been invalidated and all session data (except Id)is 
no longer available 
        System.out.println(getTime() + " (session) Destroyed:ID=" + 
session.getId()); 
    } 
    private String getTime() 
    { 
        return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString(); 
    }
}
```

If you should try the Listener make yure to call it in your web.xml with:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>YOURPACKAGENAME.MyHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Truth be told, there isn't a lot of help available for more complex problems with Tapestry on the web, which I find sad.

By setting a breakpoint in the Listener somewhere after the variable session is created, you should be able to see when and where the problem started *(or perhaps not because a session is never created, which would mean that the @Persist default value has been indeed changed by someone)*

I have a lot of throubles myself with our project and haven't found any answers so far.

Hope this one gives you a nudge in the right direction so you can find the root of your problem.